# How to check if a query string already exists

Tags: javascript, jquery, query-string

I got two different query strings: `?pid=` and `?ref=`. Currently I add the query strings using `window.history.pushState`. How can I check if there is a query string already to avoid having `?pid=foo?ref=bar` instead of `?pid=foo&ref=bar`?

Current code:

```
if (!!$.cookie('myrefcookie')) {
  var myref = $.cookie("myrefcookie")
  var target = window.location.href + '?ref=' + myref;
  window.history.pushState(null, null, target);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check [window.location.search](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_loc_search.asp) for a question mark.

```
if (!!$.cookie('myrefcookie')) {
  var myref = $.cookie("myrefcookie");
  var query = window.location.search.indexOf('?') === -1 ? '?ref=' : '&ref=';
  var target = window.location.href + query + myref;
  window.history.pushState(null, null, target);
}
```